# Python Optimization : Find the most occured sequence of 4 letters inside a 1000 letters string randomly generated

Tags: python, string

I'm here to ask help about my program.
I realise a program that raison d'être is to find the most occured four letters string on a x letters bigger string which have been generated randomly.

As example, if you would know the most occured sequence of four letters in `'abcdeabcdef'` it's pretty easy to understand that is `'abcd'` so the program will return this.

Unfortunately, my program works very slow, I mean, It take 119.7 seconds, for analyze all possibilities and display the results for only a 1000 letters string.

This is my program, right now :

```py
import random
chars = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
string = ''
for _ in range(1000):
    string += str(chars[random.randint(0, 25)])
print(string)
number = []
for ____ in range(0,26):
    print(____)
    for ___ in range(0,26):
        for __ in range(0, 26):
            for _ in range(0, 26):
                test = chars[____] + chars[___] + chars[__] + chars[_]
                print('trying :',test, end = ' ')
                number.append(0)
                for i in range(len(string) -3):
                    if string[i: i+4] == test:
                        number[len(number) -1] += 1
                print('>> finished')

_max = max(number)
for i in range(len(number)-1):
    if number[i] == _max :
        j, k, l, m = i, 0, 0, 0
        while j > 25:
            j -= 26
            k += 1
        while k > 25:
            k -= 26
            l += 1
        while l > 25:
            l -= 26
            m += 1
        Result = chars[m] + chars[l] + chars[k] + chars[j]
        print(str(Result),'occured',_max, 'times' )
```

I think there is ways to optimize it but at my level, I really don't know. Maybe the structure itself is not the best. Hope you'll gonna help me :D

Comment: Are you familiar with rolling hash, or [Rabin-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin–Karp_algorithm)?

Comment: "in 'abcdeabcdef' it's pretty easy to understand that is 'abcd' so the program will return this" hmm, what about 'bcde' it also exists 2 times.

Comment: Hint: You can use a four-letter substring as key in a dictionary, mapping it to its frequency.

Comment: @abdusco no I gonna search this way :D

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Oh yeah that true, It's will return the two

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Hum... need help about this x)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to loop through your list once to count the 4-letter sequences. You are currently looping `n*n*n*n`. You can use zip to make a four letter sequence that collects the 997 substrings, then use Counter to count them:

```
from collections import Counter
import random

chars = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']   
s = "".join([chars[random.randint(0, 25)] for _ in range(1000)])

it = zip(s, s[1:], s[2:], s[3:])
counts = Counter(it)
counts.most_common(1)
```

Edit:

`.most_common(x)` returns a list of the `x` most common strings. `counts.most_common(1)` returns a single item list with the tuple of letters and number of times it occurred like; `[(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 2)]`. So to get a string, just index into it and `join()`:

```
''.join(counts.most_common(1)[0][0])
```

Comment: @Edhyjox I haven't tried this with pyInstaller,  but collections is part of the standard python distribution, so I would think it should have no trouble. You can use this same technique to save counts to a dict too — it's just less convenient that `Counter`.

Comment: Okay ! Thank you !

Comment: I don't know how to use it at all, I mean, how to get a string that countains the for letters xD

Comment: I just don't understand it xD

Answer (score 0):

Even with your current approach of iterating through every possible 4-letter combination, you can speed up a lot by keeping a dictionary instead of a list, and testing whether the sequence occurs at all first before trying to count the occurrences:

```
counts = {}
for a in chars:
    for b in chars:
        for c in chars:
            for d in chars:
                test = a + b + c + d
                print('trying :',test, end = ' ')
                if test in s: # if it occurs at all
                    # then record how often it occurs
                    counts[test] = sum(1 for i in range(len(s)-4)
                                       if test == s[i:i+4])
```

The multiple loops can be replaced with `itertools.permutations`, though this improves readability rather than performance:

```
length = 4
for sequence in itertools.permutations(chars, length):
    test = "".join(sequence)
    if test in s:
        counts[test] = sum(1 for i in range(len(s)-length) if test == s[i:i+length])
```

You can then display the results like this:

```
_max = max(counts.values())
for k, v in counts.items():
    if v == _max:
        print(k, "occurred", _max, "times")
```

Provided that the string is shorter or around the same length as 26**4 characters, then it is much faster still to iterate through the string rather than through every combination:

```
length = 4
counts = {}
for i in range(len(s) - length):
    sequence = s[i:i+length]
    if sequence in counts:
        counts[sequence] += 1
    else:
        counts[sequence] = 1
```

This is equivalent to the [`Counter` approach already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134832/567595).